# WinRT using a double TopAppBar

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, appbar

If you look at the Bing Weather App, cou can see that it has a TopAppBar that collapses into a double AppBar at the top.

I would like to know how I could make this myself, or if any examples exist on the internet, I haven't found any myself, and don't know exactly how to start...

Thx in advance!

Comment: I've used the weather app and I don't see the 'double' effect you're referencing. The AppBar (including the TopAppBar) is a regular control that you can put whatever you want into, including expanding/collapsing controls. Is that what you mean?

Comment: If you open the Weather app and click the little arrow next to the third button, another bar will appear, this is the effect I am trying to create.

Answer (score 1):

It's just another thing in the app bar that's invisible until you hit that arrow. It could be done another way, but the point is - the app bar can have any content just as Nate said. It can change content and hide/show content in other ways than just with an edge gesture.